# Getting a Select Value with Javascript From a Rails Wildcard named select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, wildcard

So I need to call the value of a select dropdown list where I've named the select list as a wild card value (It's a wild card value because there are multiple dropdown lists I make for every iteration of User with a specific property.

```
= select_tag "#{user.id}", options_for_select([["User", "0"], ["Admin", "1"]]),
    :onchange => "setTimeout('admin_change(#{user.id});', 300);
```

So, then in a javascript block at the top I have this

```
function admin_change(id) {
  change_value = $(#id).val();
```

Following this I execute a different $.AJAX command based on the change_value pulled.

Is there a way for me to execute this?

Comment: what isn't working for you there?

Comment: The $(#id) doesn't correspond to the function's id.

Answer (score 0):

Give to all selects you need to manipulate a class, then:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.myselects').change(function(){
       var user_id = $(this).val(); 
       /* 
       if value is not your user id, just add it to options as data-* attribute 
       (ex: data-user-id="123"), and select it using:
       */
       var user_id = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-user-id');

       // and, at this point, do anything you need: ajax calls, etc...
    });
});
```